# How to hide/invisible a button in odoo helpdesk using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, odoo-15

In Odoo version 15 I created a Js cod Based on the button Accept and Deny and I created a boolean field in **res users model**. The workflow is: if the user clicks the Accept button the boolean field makes True and clicks the Denay button it change to False state. The Functionality is working well. Currently, the issue am facing is both buttons are showing on page refresh time. How to solve this ... Actually I want to show only One button based on the user availability( based on the Boolean field)

IN XML SIDE:

```
<templates>
     <t t-extend="ListView.buttons" t-name="AttendenceMarkListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
<!--            <t t-if="widget.isAvailable()">-->


            <button t-if="widget.modelName == 'helpdesk.ticket'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-secondary-new o_button_accept_ticket">
                Accept
            </button>
            <button t-if="widget.modelName == 'helpdesk.ticket'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-secondary-new o_button_deny_ticket">
                Deny
            </button>
<!--                  </t>-->
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

and in JS side:

```
odoo.define('attendance.button.tree', function (require) {
"use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var ListController = require('web.ListController');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView');
    var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');
    var rpc = require('web.rpc')

    var includeDict = {
        buttons_template: 'AttendenceMarkListView.buttons',
        renderButtons: function ($node) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self = this;
            this.$buttons.on('click', '.o_button_accept_ticket', this._onAcceptAttendance.bind(this));
            this.$buttons.on('click', '.o_button_deny_ticket', this._onDeclineAttendance.bind(this));
        },
        _onAcceptAttendance: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.$('.o_button_accept_ticket').hide();
            this.$('.o_button_deny_ticket').show();
            rpc.query({
            model: 'helpdesk.ticket',
            method: 'user_accept_ticket',
            args: [],
        }, {
            shadow: true,
        }).then(function () {

        });
        },
         _onDeclineAttendance: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.$('.o_button_deny_ticket').hide();
            this.$('.o_button_accept_ticket').show();
            rpc.query({
            model: 'helpdesk.ticket',
            method: 'user_decline_ticket',
            args: [],
        }, {
            shadow: true,
        }).then(function () {

        });
        },
    };

    ListController.include(includeDict);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Template :**

```
<templates>
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons" t-name="AttendenceMarkListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
                 <button id="button_accept" t-if="widget.modelName == 'helpdesk.ticket'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-secondary-new o_button_accept_ticket">
                    Accept
                </button>
                <button id="button_reject" t-if="widget.modelName == 'helpdesk.ticket'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-secondary-new o_button_deny_ticket">
                    Deny
                </button>

        </t>
    </t>
</templates>

**Js Side:**
odoo.define('attendance.button.tree', function (require) {
"use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var ListController = require('web.ListController');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView');
    var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');
    var rpc = require('web.rpc')

    var includeDict = {
        buttons_template: 'AttendenceMarkListView.buttons',
        renderButtons: function ($node) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self = this;
            this.$buttons.on('click', '.o_button_accept_ticket', this._onAcceptAttendance.bind(this));
            this.$buttons.on('click', '.o_button_deny_ticket', this._onDeclineAttendance.bind(this));

        },
        _onAcceptAttendance: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.$('.o_button_accept_ticket').hide();
            this.$('.o_button_deny_ticket').show();
            return self._rpc({
            model: 'helpdesk.ticket',
            method: 'user_accept_ticket',
            args: [],
            }).then(function (data) {

            });
        },

         _onDeclineAttendance: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.$('.o_button_deny_ticket').hide();
            this.$('.o_button_accept_ticket').show();
            return self._rpc({
                model: 'helpdesk.ticket',
                method: 'user_decline_ticket',
                args: [],
            }).then(function (data) {
                      

                });
        },



    };

    ListController.include(includeDict);

});
```